# Simply show pictures in webview using buttons (Android SDK)

Tags: java, javascript, android, sdk, webview

Can someone please help? I just want to be able to open the picture when the button is pressed.. Eventually assign a new image to other buttons. I am testing this directly on the phone (GS3) and when I press the button I get a black screen with an upside down android logo in the top left and file:///res/raw/process.png as a link in the middle. When i hit the link nothing happens. I am a beginner, if you have a solution could you please post it in a way that I could just cut and past it. The picture is in the location stated, maybe it has something to do with how I am handling webView. The buttons and webView are on the same XML because I don't know how to use intents. I am just trying to hide the buttons and show the webView. Thanks in advance, been working this for 12 hours and have to be up for work in 3 :(  I own [www.FirstSergeant.com](http://www.firstsergeant.com) if there is anything I can help you with in return just let me know. 
Thanks again
Jesse

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private WebView picView;
    private LinearLayout layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button appBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.process);
    appBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                picView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
                layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
                layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                picView.setBackgroundColor(0);
                picView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                picView.loadUrl("file:///res/raw/process.png");
                picView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                picView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            }                

        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
 }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to assign `picView` and `layout` inside `onCreate()`, not inside the button click.

Secondly, your image url is wrong, and will result in a file not found exception. Try:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button appBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.process);
    picView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.pic_view);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    appBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                picView.setBackgroundColor(0);
                picView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                picView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/process.png");
                picView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                picView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            }                

        });
    }
```

Comment: WOW that was fast! This worked flawlessly THANK YOU! However, when I hit the back button on my phone it just closes the app. I guess I will need to learn how to open the picture in a different class. I guess now what I am looking to do is based on the button I push in my menu class open that .png in the view class under the webView. Looks like I have a really good start here I just need to learn how to carry the button info over to the view class. I have been working this for so long on something that must seem simple to you. Thanks again for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @user1812725 Please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark if it answered the question. Also, you're seeing the default back button behavior, but if you want to do something specific on the clicking of the back button, you could try overriding onBackPressed()